# How does limiting an UIAlertView's input to specific characters work?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a very simple `UIAlertView` with a title, a text field and and ok button. I'd like to limit what can be entered in the text field to alphanumeric characters (0-9 a-z A-Z). This is how I first made the alert view:

```
UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Client id"
                                                 message: @"some title"
                                                delegate: self
                                       cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok"
                                       otherButtonTitles: nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alert show];
```

I tried looking for an answer first and it seems everyone suggests to implement
`- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`
and then add the textField to the alert like this:

```
- (void)someInitialisationMethod {
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Client id"
                                                     message: @"some title"
                                                    delegate: self
                                           cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok"
                                           otherButtonTitles: nil];
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
    [alert addSubview:textField];
    [alert show];
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"];
    for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
        unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
        if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) {
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

I tried this and added both `UITextFieldDelegate` and `UIAlertViewDelegate` to my view controller. My problem is that the text field doesn't even get added to my alert view. I just end up with an alert with only a title and an ok button.

How do I properly add the text field to my alert? And did I implement the rest of the solution right? I ripped the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method from [this SO question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738321/how-to-disable-letter-characters-in-uitextfield)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say why you abandoned the first way, but this is the way to go. You can't add views to UIAlertView. Adding subviews to an alert was always discouraged, but since iOS7 it's impossible.

So stick to your first method. And don't forget to set the delegate of the embedded textField:

```
UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Client id"
                                                 message: @"some title"
                                                delegate: self
                                       cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok"
                                       otherButtonTitles: nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

UITextField *textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
textField.delegate = self;

[alert show];
```

Comment: I didn't know you could set the text field's delegate like that so I went looking for ways to still limit the character input, which let me to the second version. This indeed works perfectly, thanks.